# JSON2CSV install/setup issue (via Go)

Tags: go

I'm attempting to install https://github.com/jehiah/json2csv. The problem is apparently tied to my noob status w.r.t. Bash.

System: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Load instruction:

```
$ go get github.com/jehiah/json2csv
```

Go is installed:

```
$ which go ==> /usr/bin/go
```

~/.bashrc setup:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/bin/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/projects/go
```

The package seems to download correctly:

```
$ cd projects/go
$ tree
$ > bin > json2csv
  > src > github.com
        ...
$ ls bin -l
$ > -rwxrwxr-x 1 <user> <user> 55400 Feb  5 13:57 json2csv
```

But $json2csv isn't recognized, even from the same directory. I'm sure this is a noob problem, but I haven't cracked it yet. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Add $GOPATH/bin to your PATH variable in your shell,

for bash:

```
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```